# Sony Vegas rendering only audio plus first frame of project

Tags: vegas-pro

I have Sony Vegas Pro 13.0 and have been using it for a while now without any issues. I have been working on a video project and rendered several drafts so far, all without any issues. I finished my final edit and followed some tips i found online to play with my project properties and played around with different render templates. However, when I finally rendered my video, the result was just the audio of the file with a small picture of the first frame of my video as the only visual. I have tried everything I can think of, including re installing SV. I am in need of a quick answer. Please help.

Comment: Found the fix, although bemused at the stupidity of it. Group all the layers as one.

Comment: I'm confused - was the grouping the problem or solution? It shouldn't be the solution, because layer grouping is NOT required for a proper render.

Comment: @Mulvya It was the solution. As confused as you are. I was at the point that I had nothing to lose and was just trying anything. Luckily, something worked.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing a screenshot of the timeline and some details, maybe I can diagnose why the grouping solved it. Could be useful for someone with the same root cause.

Comment: @Mulvya Here is the link to the screenshots. Don't hesitate to ask any other questions.

http://imgur.com/a/m6Weh

Comment: @Mulvya Same problem again. Grouping doesn't fix. Beyond frustrated.